# put a hash in javascript cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies, hash

i want to include a hash in javascript cookie since i have a list of things to remember... can anyone tel how to set the cookie and the method to retrive it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set Cookie in JavaScript like this:

```
document.cookie = 'somekey=somevalue; expires=Thu, 2 Aug 2011 21:17:11 UTC; path=/'
```

Codes to create, read & erase cookies in JavaScript ( by [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html) ):

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
```

Comment: i need to include more than one name-value pairs in a single cookie.. is that possible??

Comment: Just join and split on a delimiter. For example |

Comment: yes, mplungjan is correct. you can add as many name-value pairs as you wish using delimiter.

Comment: hi while using the page some variables are set as cookie and I can't delete that. It also joins with my cookie. I dont know why it behaves like this. One more problem is I couldn't set expiry date b'coz of the automatically set cookie. only name value pairs I can set with my cookie.  If I set expiry date my name value pair also not assigned to the cookie. can you help me?